# ByPassing Google App Engine SDK to allow black listed classes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, postgresql, sdk

Is there a way to circumbent google app engine sdk to allow the usage of classes that are not present in the GAE JRE white list? I know the app that I would be building will not run in appspot, but at least in my development server, I need to access a postgresql database(java.net.socket.*) and generate some files(java.io.FileWriter) in my development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your code in another servlet container, such as [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).

Comment: Thanks, never thought we could just copy the war folder of a GWT/App engine web application project then paste it into the /webapp folder of jetty or tomcat then rename it to your project name. thanks. :)